# How can I remove the last two rows from Minizic output?

Tags: command-line, output, minizinc

When I execute a program of minizinc, the last two rows appear but I do not want them in my output.
E.g.

```
10 10
6
3 3 0 7
3 4 7 6
3 6 7 0
3 7 0 0
4 4 3 0
4 6 3 4
----------
==========
```

I got it using this kind of command

```
minizinc --solver Gecode -p <cores> -t 300000 <model> <in_file>
```

How can I fix this problem from command line?

Comment: What OS? What shell?

Comment: I am using windows 10 and the command line of windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines represent the status of the solving process. By default solutions are separated using "----------" and the search is marked as complete using "==========".

You can change these using the following flags:

```
  --soln-comma <s>, --solution-comma <s>
    Specify the string used to separate solutions.
    The default is the empty string.
  --unsat-msg (--unsatisfiable-msg), --unbounded-msg, --unsatorunbnd-msg,
        --unknown-msg, --error-msg, --search-complete-msg <msg>
    Specify solution status messages. The defaults:
    "=====UNSATISFIABLE=====", "=====UNSATorUNBOUNDED=====", "=====UNBOUNDED=====",
    "=====UNKNOWN=====", "=====ERROR=====", "==========", respectively.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `head -n -2` with pipe:

```
minizinc --solver Gecode -p <cores> -t 300000 <model> <in_file> | head -n -2`
```

Comment: This only works if you always are in the scenario where only the (proven) optimal solution is output. Whenever multiple solutions, a solution that is not optimal, or a different solving status is return, this will fail. Instead I would suggest using the flags of the MiniZinc compiler as suggested in my answer.